# Citation and Referring doesn't work on VS Studio Code

Tags: citing, ref, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code for my Tex editor.
Everything works fine except when I try to **\ref** a paragraph or **\cite** something from the bibliography.

Could you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: What's not working, autocompletion? Or is there a problem in the output file?

Comment: The output file shows [?] instead of the right citation.

Comment: This should have nothing to do with VS Studio Code, but suspect demonstrates that you are not writing the (La)TeX properly. Produce a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was from where I compile the tex file(from the terminal) and the missed 9 in
\begin{thebibliography}{9}.